# R - In new dataframe: if cell matches another column of same row, then

Tags: r, dataframe

```
d <- data.frame(B1 = c(1,2,3,4),B2 = c(0,1,2,3))
d$total=rowSums(d)

B1 B2 total
1  0  1
2  1  3
3  2  5
4  3  7
```

Using the dataframe above, I want to create a new dataframe with the following logic:

Going by rows, if cells (B1:B2) matches d$total, return 1, else 0.

Ideally output to look like:

```
B1n B2n
1   0
0   0
0   0
0   0
```

What is the best way to do this in R?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare first 2 columns with `total` value.

```
res <- +(d[1:2] == d$total)
res
#     B1 B2
#[1,]  1  0
#[2,]  0  0
#[3,]  0  0
#[4,]  0  0
```

The result is a matrix, if you want dataframe as output you can do `res <- data.frame(res)`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternate way to solve this problem. You can use dplyr::transmute which is the opposite of dplyr::mutate which will give you two separate columns. Inside transmute are just conditions.

```
library(dplyr)

newdf <- d %>% transmute(B1n=ifelse(B1+B2==B1,1,0),B2n=ifelse(B1+B2==B2,1,0))
> newdf
  B1n B2n
1   1   0
2   0   0
3   0   0
4   0   0
```

Comment: Can you also please explain this answer, as many new users might struggle to understand what's going on. Thanks